# Hive not starting up

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to get hive started on my Linux system. It gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.TableDesc.setProperties(TableDesc.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.TableDesc.<init>(TableDesc.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PlanUtils.getDefaultTableDesc(PlanUtils.java:458)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.<clinit>(Utilities.java:681)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:709)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:750)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private volatile java.lang.String java.net.URI.string accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @3e849b9e
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.StringInternUtils.<clinit>(StringInternUtils.java:57)
    ... 16 more
```

I am unable to figure out why this is happening. I even changed the JAVA version to 8 on my system, but the error persists.

Comment: Exactly what did you download for Hive, and what commands are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm too late but here's the solution that worked for me in Intellij for the same problem:
Please add "**--add-opens java. Base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED**" to your VM option.
For intellij : Open Run/debug Configurations > Create an application for your file if its already not there > Add VM Option > add this config in VM "**--add-opens java. Base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED**"

Comment: While this worked for me there are some issues in the above answer due to formatting: I used `export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="--add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED $HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS"`

Comment: Source https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-standard/issues/13#issuecomment-1207808508